# Cannot add two numbers correctly without using parseFloat in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition

I came across this problem. It adding numbers using parseFloat or parseInt.
IF textbox1 value is 4 and textbox2 value is 2 then i got output as (see script)

My doubt is why in **addition** alone

> `parseFloat($('#txt1').val()) + parseFloat($('#txt2').val())`

gives correct value but

> `parseFloat($('#txt1').val() + $('#txt2').val())`

is not giving correct value whereas

- `parseFloat($('#txt1').val() - $('#txt2').val())`,
- `parseFloat($('#txt1').val() / $('#txt2').val())`,
- `parseFloat($('#txt1').val() * $('#txt2').val())`

are giving correct value.
Its simple but i couldn't find solution.

=====jQuery

```
   function Calculate() {                                              //--> Output
     $('#lbl1').html(parseFloat($('#txt1').val() + $('#txt2').val())); //--> 42
     $('#lbl2').html(parseFloat($('#txt1').val()) + parseFloat($('#txt2').val())); //--> 6
     $('#lbl3').html(parseFloat(4 + 2));                               //--> 6

     $('#lbl4').html(parseFloat($('#txt1').val() - $('#txt2').val())); //--> 2
     $('#lbl5').html(parseFloat($('#txt1').val() * $('#txt2').val())); //--> 8
     $('#lbl6').html(parseFloat($('#txt1').val() / $('#txt2').val())); //--> 2
  }
```

=====HTML

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Calculate"  onclick="Calculate()" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label id="lbl1">
                </label>
                |
                <label id="lbl2">
                </label>
                |
                <label id="lbl3">
                </label>
                |
                <label id="lbl4">
                </label>
                |
                <label id="lbl5">
                </label>
                |
                <label id="lbl6">
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This is because the + operator is also used in strings, while the - and * operators are not. With loose-typed languages like this you get this behaviour.

Comment: I'm surprised no one suggested the excellent jQuery arithmetic plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$.val()` returns a string value.

So in your first example you convert both returned strings to numbers and the calculation is fine.

If you use `parseFloat($('#txt1').val() + $('#txt2').val())` the `+` does not work as the arithmetic operator, but as a string concatenation. So you concatenate both strings and convert them afterwards, which gives a wrong result.

The examples using `-` will work, as there is no string operation using `-` and by thus alls values get implicitly converted to a number *before* the operation is applied.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#txt1').val() + $('#txt2').val()` it gives String value

you can not use -  , *  , /operator on strings

`parseFloat($('#txt1').val()),  parseFloat($('#txt2').val())`  returns numbers not strings