# How do I write a map literal in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, literals

In Python, I can write a map literal like this:

```
mymap = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three" : 3}
```

How can I do the equivalent in C++11?

Answer (score 57):

You can actually do this:

```
std::map<std::string, int> mymap = {{"one", 1}, {"two", 2}, {"three", 3}};
```

What is actually happening here is that `std::map` stores an `std::pair` of the key value types, in this case `std::pair<const std::string,int>`. This is only possible because of c++11's new uniform initialization syntax which in this case calls a constructor overload of `std::pair<const std::string,int>`. In this case `std::map` has a constructor with an `std::intializer_list` which is responsible for the outside braces.

So unlike python's any class you create can use this syntax to initialize itself as long as you create a constructor that takes an initializer list (or uniform initialization syntax is applicable)

Comment: Actually `std::pair<const std::string, int>`.  But they take the same sorts of initializers.

Comment: @aschepler good point fixed it, I guess the key is always given a const qualifier

Comment: I don't think that's accurate. `{"one",1}` is uniform initialization (potentially even _aggregate initialization_ if std::pair is actually POD). Only the outer `{}` is an initializer list. It still _works_ because of uniform initialization (otherwise `mymap({ {a,b}, {c,d} })` would have been required)

Comment: @sehe it's still valid to refer to it as an initializer list, but I'll edit the answer to make it clearer

Comment: @aaronman Actually it isn't. In fact, overload resolution is very specific in the presence of initializer lists so the distinction is quite good to make (signatures taking an initializer list are always preferred for uniform initialization; uniform initialization does ***not*** imply an initializer list)

Comment: @sehe what would refer to the `{...}` used in uniform initialization then

Comment: Your answer is still not accurate. As @sehe mentions, when using uniform initialization, a constructor taking initializer lists is always preferred, and if that is not available/non-viable, then other constructors are attempted for matches. Since `pair` is not an aggregate, and doesn't have a constructor that accepts an initializer list, it's that last part that makes the above expression work.

Comment: @aaronman You would refer to that as... _uniform initialization_. And you could add that it invokes a constructor overload. (Yeah, it's a shame. Uniform initialization isn't really that uniform :()

Comment: @Praetorian which part specifically is wrong, I'm a little confused

Comment: @aaronman This part *either uniform initialization, a call to a constructor that takes an initializer list or aggregate initialization*. It's none of those, it actually matches `std::pair`'s constructor that takes two arguments (for each of the contained types)

Comment: @Praetorian so when you match to a constructor are using ....

Comment: @aaronman I don't know of a succinct phrase to refer to it, it's just plain old construction that has been enabled by the new uniform initialization syntax.

Comment: @Praetorian I think the lack of terminology for this syntax has been confusing me

Answer (score 27):

You may do this:

```
std::map<std::string, int> mymap = {{"one", 1}, {"two", 2}, {"three", 3}};
```

Comment: I couldn't find the answer on SO, so I added it to save other programmers some time. SO actually encourages this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @abw333 arguably that's not for trivia "look-it-up" reference style questions... Just imagine "How do I add two numbers in Jquery" (interestingly: [Adding numbers in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117985/adding-numbers-in-jquery) :)

Comment: @sehe I'm just trying to help. I spent a few minutes Googling for this and had no success and eventually had to ask someone to figure out the answer. I didn't see it on SO, so I posted this so that the answer could be more easily found.

Comment: You shouldn't share your personal opinion on language x vs language y in SO. This syntax is fine because unlike Python, `std::map` isn't a built-in type in the core language and it's statically typed rather than dynamically typed. It's like comparing apples to cars.

Comment: @Rapptz You're right. I edited my response.