# How can I use objects/hashes in C++ like objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, object, hash

In JavaScript I have a function -- new-able, treated like a class -- that receives two objects as paramters:

```
function StochasticStudy(inputs, outputMap) {
    this.inputs = inputs;
    this.outputMap = outputMap;
}

var inputs = {length: 10, averageLength: 3};
var outputMap = {K: 'stochastic10K', D: 'stochastic10D'};
new StochasticStudy(inputs, outputMap);
```

I need to do the same thing in C++. I know I could have a class with a constructor that receives all parameters individually:

```
class StochasticStudy {
    StochasticStudy(length, averageLength, KMap, DMap);
};

StochasticStudy study = new StochasticStudy(10, 3, "stochastic10K", "stochastic10D");
```

But I don't like this. I want the inputs grouped together and the outputMap grouped separately -- especially since some inputs can be optional.

How can I achieve this in standard C++? I'd prefer to not pull in an obscure third-party library to do this and instead use as vanilla yet simple an approach as possible.

Comment: That is irrelevant, but if you must know, it is because Node.js does not support Double type and only supports floating points. Also I intend to use CUDA for part of my application, and I want everything in the same language.

Comment: I think this as close as you can get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230097/how-do-i-write-a-map-literal-in-c11

Comment: It's not "irrelevant".

Comment: I've already decided on my language. I just need an answer to the question posed, and that's it. Thank you.